# How to avoid duplicate line color on d3js?

Tags: d3.js

I'm using d3.js to make a line chart and if my chart has more than 12 lines the colors starts to duplicate. Is there a way to prevent the color from duplicating?

Here is where I set my color line.

```
    const z = d3.scaleOrdinal()
            .domain(chartData.map(function(c) { return c['name']; }))
            .range(d3.schemePaired);
```

Comment: The `schemePaired` scheme only has 12 colors.  There's a couple of schemes of 20 colors (`category20`)....

Comment: Or use one of the color interpolators from https://github.com/d3/d3-scale-chromatic. Convert your key or index in the range [0..1] and call the interpolator.